# Sending an object as a query string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, axios, json-api

I'm using the JSPON API spec via fast_jsonapi gem and trying to create a [sparse fieldset](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#sparse-fieldsets) to send to my rails controller. The ideal query string would look like this:

```
/locations?fields[location]=name&fields[location]=address
```

But I end up getting an encoded url like this:

```
locations?fields=%7B%22location%22:[%22name%22,%22address%22]%7D
```

I pass the field option into my controller

```
API::Admin::LocationSerializer.new(locations, { fields: params[:fields] }).serialized_json
```

But get the error:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

This is how I'm passing my query string via axios:

```
axios.get('locations', {
  params: {
    fields: {
      location: ['name', 'address'],
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: By default, browsers encodes urls. I would recommend you have a decoder code set in your server code(rails controller). Decode the encoded url params and in the server.

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your issue but accordingly to the spec it should be comma separated list per resource type. So instead of `/locations?fields[location]=name&fields[location]=address` your URL should be `/locations?fields[location]=address,name`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `paramsSerializer` option for this to work. Something like:

```
const qs = require('qs');

axios.get('locations', {
  params: {
    fields: {
      location: ['name', 'address'],
    },
  },
  paramsSerializer: params => qs.stringify(params)
});
```

Comment: Is my url supposed to look any different? Seems like it's putting out the same request.

Comment: you might have to play around with the exact use of `qs.stringify` in your case, it should look different yeah

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting close. I passed the option not to encode my query string and got this: `locations?fields[location][0]=name&fields[location][1]=address`. I think the only thing it's doing now is 0 indexing my fields. Not sure if this is right. Getting a rails related error: 'undefined method `to_sym' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007fd8dd012e90> Did you mean? to_s`